# Linux: Removing "Thumbs.db" entries from folders

Tags: linux

I have a set of nested folders which I transferred from Window 10 to a Linux PC. Without realizing it I also transferred the "Thumbs.db" entries. I say "entries" because when I do a "ls" command on one of the folders, it will show the .jpg files, other folders and also the "Thumbs.db" entry, but it is not colored/highlighted like the files nor the folders.
[image: Shows the Thumbs.db entry in a screen shot]

I can remove the Thumbs.db entry with a `rm images/folder/Thumbs.db` command, but that seems to be a manual/one-at-a-time operation. "find" does not find them `find images/ -name "Thumbs.db"` either with or without the double-quotes. Also running with sudo has no effect.

Is there a easy way to get rid of these Thumbs.db entries? Thanks...RDK

Comment: `find` should be able to "find" them. `find /path/to/images/ -name "Thumbs.db" -delete` should work just fine.

Comment: What type of filesystem do you use on your Linux machine? Is it one that is case-insensitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an additional web search, I found this command with finds the Thumbs.db entries so they can be deleted.  "iname" seems to be the key option:

```
find images/folder/ -iname Thumbs.db
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shell can do "globbing", automatic creation of file names from wildcards.

A simple

```
rm images/*/Thumbs.db
```

will delete all the Thumbs.db from direct subfolders of images, so images/a/Thumbs.db, images/wedding/Thumbs.db, images/boat/Thumbs.db…;

Assuming you use bash (which is the default shell on most systems), you can also enable recursive wildcards

```
shopt -s globstar
rm images/**/Thumbs.db
```

will go into all subdirectories, and subdirectories, and subdirectories… and delete all Thumbs.db.

But if `find` doesn't find them, chances are they aren't actually called Thumbs.db. We can try whether it's because capitalization is different:

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nocaseglob
rm images/**/Thumbs.db
```

will also delete any thumbs.db, THUMBS.dB, tHumbs.DB…

Comment: I have updated my question with a screen shot showing the "Thumbs.db" entry in a folder list.  As I said above I can remove it using a RM command, but FIND does not find the files.